# Can I use nsq_to_file uitility with docker compose?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, automation, nsq

I work with [nsq_to_file utility](https://nsq.io/components/utilities.html#nsq_to_file) while running some automation code, I wanted to automate that utility as a docker-compose service. I can't find any documentation about using this utility with docker. I use it as follows:

`./nsq_to_file --lookupd-http-address=<http_address> --topic=ta-gcp-test -output-dir=/path/to/local/dir -filename-format=local_file_name`

Does anyone have any input on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a Docker container with the nsq_to_file executable, it would look like this:

```
#
# build container
#
FROM golang:1.17-alpine as builder

RUN apk update && apk add git
RUN git clone https://github.com/nsqio/nsq
RUN cd nsq/apps/nsq_to_file/ && CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags="-w -s" -o /nsq_to_file .

#
# scratch release container
#
FROM scratch as scratch

COPY --from=builder /nsq_to_file /nsq_to_file
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs /etc/ssl/certs

# Run as non-root user for secure environments
USER 59000:59000

ENTRYPOINT [ "/nsq_to_file" ]
```

You can then build it and run it:

`docker build  -t oliver006/nsq_to_file -f Dockerfile .`

`docker run --rm  oliver006/nsq_to_file --lookupd-http-address=<http_address> --topic=ta-gcp-test ...`